# php session timeout with nginx

Tags: php, session, nginx

When I write this code,it seems right

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
    echo $_SESSION['test'];//'test'
```

but when I change the code like this and refresh the browser:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['test'];//nothing
```

In my lamp(linux+apache+mysql+php),I can get 'test' in second code,but not in lnmp(linux+nginx+mysql+php)

In php.ini:

```
 session.auto_start = 1
```

In nginx conf:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { 
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?s=$1  last; 
    } 
}


location ~ \.php$ { 
    root           html; 
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; 
    fastcgi_index  index.php; 
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
    include        fastcgi_params; 
}
```

Help me plz.

Comment: Does the php user have access to the folder where it stores sessions? `echo $_SESSION['test'];//'test'` works because sessions are saved at the end of the script.

Comment: You're right,"/var/lib/php/session" only got "drwxrwx---",I change it with "chmod -R 777 ./" and fixed

Comment: It'll be better to just add the nginx user to the appropriate group instead of giving rwx to others.